# Prevent a subdirectory from getting deleted / enforce a directory structure

Tags: linux, permissions, directory, rm

imagine the following folder structure

> ../documents
>
> ../documents/templates

I have two user groups:

- editors
- managers

Users of both groups should be able to

- create new files
- modify any files
- delete any files

in ../documents.

Both groups should also be able to read any files in ../documents/templates.

Only users in group "managers" should be able to

- create new files
- modify any files
- delete any files

in ../documents/templates.

The directory "../documents/templates" should be undeletable for both groups!

How can I achieve that? I came to the conclusion, that this isn't possible with Linux (even with POSIX ACLs), because you need to set g=rwx for "documents", which will allow users of both groups to create/delete/modify **any** files in that directory... but +w also allows the deletion of the subdirectory "templates" and I don't know a way to deny that.

Answer (score 4):

No one will be able to delete `../documents/templates` if it contains anything else. So, you could create a subdirectory `../documents/templates/.hidden`, with `000` permissions, and put an empty file inside that (well, *before* setting the `000` permissions, obviously). Then `rmdir ../documents/templates` will fail, as will `rmdir ../documents/templates/.hidden`.

Edit: to borrow from another answer that was deleted, if you're superuser, you could do this instead, which is a little simpler:

```
cd ../documents/templates
touch .locked
chattr +i .locked
```

(`chattr` needs to be run as superuser.)