# Make directory contents modifiable, including creation of new files, but prevent directory itself from being deleted

Tags: permissions

I have been tasked to set up a new server for our web project hosting. I'm a developer, so my systems administration level is quite low.

I have come up with a somewhat simple solution that each project will have it's own UNIX user and that the webroot will be under user's `$HOME`.

The structure is as simple as:

- `/home/<user>/web`

  - `/home/<user>/web/log` — log files.
  - `/home/<user>/web/www` — web document root.
  - `/home/<user>/web/www/public` — just a practice that has come up with various web application frameworks to separate document root from public root.

Now, I want to set permissions in such a way that:

- `/home/<user>/web` — can neither be deleted, nor new files/directories added. `chown root:root` helps here.

  - `/home/<user>/web/log` — is read only to the user, which I can also manage by a simple `chown root:root`.
  - `/home/<user>/web/www` — this shouldn't be possible to delete/edit, but contents freely modifiable (except `public`). Create, delete, edit both files and directories.
  - `/home/<user>/web/www/public` — shouldn't be possible to delete/edit, but contents freely modifiable.

For other security and isolation related features, I have opted to use [firejail](/questions/tagged/firejail).

So far I have tried `chattr +a` - it allowed me to add new contents, edit contents, but I couldn't delete them.

While writing the question, similar question section showed [Prevent a subdirectory from getting deleted / enforce a directory structure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20351/prevent-a-subdirectory-from-getting-deleted-enforce-a-directory-structure), which works and I am looking to use it for now.

But are there any other, more transparent ways of setting these directories up as such?

Comment: Also backups, as users will undoubtably find other ways to mess things up besides deleting the directory itself

Comment: @thrig yeah, those are already in place.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a directory requires write permission on its parent. The permissions and ownership of the directory are irrelevant. So if you want to prevent deleting `/home/theuser/web`, it is necessary and sufficient¹ to ensure that the user does not have write permission on `/home/theuser`.

Do note that when you write “a `chown root:root` helps here”, that's *on the parent directory* to prevent its deletion, *and* on the directory itself to prevent adding or removing files (but not modifying existing files).

Note also that to make `/home/theuser/web/log` read-only in a useful way, it is not enough to ensure that the user does not have write permission (and does not own the directory). If the user was allowed to write to `/home/theuser/web` (or `/home/theuser` or `/home` or `/`) then they could rename `/home/theuser/web/log` (or `/home/theuser/web`, etc.) and create a new directory `log` which they would own.

For `/home/theuser/web/www` and `/home/theuser/web/www/public`, you can make `www` and `www/public` owned by root, but give the user write permissions, and set the sticky bit on `www`. When a directory has the sticky bit, there is an additional requirement to remove files inside it (including immediate subdirectories — directories are a type of file): a user may only remove files that they own. This way, `public` will only be removable by its owner (root), but anything else can be freely manipulated by the user.

```
chown root:root web/www web/www/public
chmod u=rwx,go= web/www web/www/public
chmod +t web/www
setfacl -m u:theuser:rwx web/www web/www/public
```

Note that it could be any non-theuser ownership, it doesn't have to be root.

¹  <sub>Under reasonable assumptions, i.e. all necessary traversal rights, no relevant SELinux rule, etc.</sub>